# How do I fix an "Invalid Program gbuffers_textured_lit" error in Minecraft - GLSL Shaders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, windows-8

I installed the GLSL Shaders Mod for Minecraft 1.5.2 with Magic Launcher.

When I try to open a ShaderPack called `SEUS v10.0 Lite.zip`, I get a message:

> [Shaders] Error: Invalid program gbuffers_textured_lit

and a red screen (screenshot 1).

But with another pack called `SEUS v10.0 Standard.zip`, it gives me some small, blue screens in the bottom-left corner (screenshot 2).  It also gives me the message:

> [Shaders] Error: Invalid program gbuffers_textured_lit

**Screenshot 1:**
[image: screenshot 1]
**Screenshot 2:**
[image: screenshot2]
Does anyone know how to fix this?

*I am using Windows 8 and Minecraft 1.5.2 (While using Magic Launcher for mod installing).*

Comment: What version of Minecraft did you install the mod on?

Comment: minecraft 1.5.2 with magic launcher

Comment: Could just be my imagination, but could this be a library that should be installed/is found through another installation method of these mods?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's modded Minecraft tech support.

Answer (score 4):

> Change line 47 in composite.vsh from 'float timePow = 2.0f;' to 'float timePow = 3.0f;   Changing it will get rid of the Invalid Program Composite error.

--[Source](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/940974-162sonic-ethers-unbelievable-shaders-and-glsl-shaders-mod/page__st__17120)

Possible change for Minecraft 1.6.2, may work for minecraft 1.5.2. Let me know if this helps, I'll keep looking otherwise.

Comment: I have reinstalled all packages, i have changed 'float timePow = 2.0f;' to 'float timePow = 3.0f' and i get even more errors (even with unchanged), with dome packs it works, but with SEUS v10.0 standart.zip not. errors: invalid program invalid_textured_lit and invalid program final.

Comment: What other mods are you using @nelson2tm?

Comment: optifine, because it is required for the glsl shaders mod @cole-busby